# Insert Shapes Within a Parameter Pallet Solver

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a pallet solver that will take data entered in cells to build a pallet.

Below is an example of the data input. For each item, you would enter the number of cases, the length = depth. The Width and Height of each case, and the Ti Hi (how high the product can be stacked and how many cases are on each row). I have scaled inches down into cm to fit on the screen and be legible, as a note. (this is also a rough draft so it doesn't look the neatest.)

[image]

Below is my code thus far to insert the shape( rectangle) based on the input. I think that using a 3-D shape would be better since I have to enter a depth (length) of the case:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Dim rge As range
Set rge = ws.range("B10")
Dim width As Single
width = ws.range("E11").Value
Dim height As Single
height = ws.range("F11").Value


For i = 1 To rge.Value
    ws.Shapes.AddShape msoShapeRectangle, 50, 50, width, height
    
    Next
```

The cases need to insert right next to each other, or on top, and within the parameters of the pallet (121.92 x 101.6 cm). I think i have to create a loop?

I have scaled down the picture to fit a standard pallet 48x40.

Please ignore my little notes in the screen.

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: What is your goal? To just draw a picture (knowing already how many packages go in each row/column/level) or to calculate how many fit. If it is about calculating what rules would you expect to follow? What do you consider an optimal packing? Because packing a pallete is not only to get as many packages in each level it is also about stability of the entire pallete. For example if you put the same pattern in each level it gets more and more unstable with each level. If you can alternate the pattern it is much more stable. So you see that is not an easy task and you need to define the rules.

Comment: yes, essentially to visualize and how to "build the pallet". It would have to be based on the TI-HI so technically the pallet will be stable depending on that because that is set up through vendors who say how high the pallet can be stacked to remain stable. so I have all the parameters met, it's just executing what that would look like. and also depending on the case count.  there may be situations where there could be multiple packages with different dimensions but I figured it's easier to start with one item and build onto that later. does that makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how to calculate 2 patterns how to put packages on a pallet (including alternate patterns to fill up spaces).

Note that alternated patterns are usually more staple than patterns that are the same on each level. In this example the second pattern would probably be more stable if turned by 180 degrees on each level.

This is just an example, the second pattern would get even more stable if you put in more variatons of that for example putting one of the 2 packages in the bottom into the middle (alternated) etc. There are a lot of variations possible but if you want a software to cover all of them that would be kinda hard to define those rules. So this is just to give a basic idea about how complex that task can be.

```
Option Explicit

Public Const PackageName As String = "Package_"
Public Const PaletteName As String = "Palette_"

Public Sub PrintPatterns()
    Const Factor As Double = 1
    Const CanvasOffsetDepth As Double = 150
    Const CanvasOffsetWidth As Double = 50
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Tabelle1
    
    ClearShapes ws, PackageName
    ClearShapes ws, PaletteName
    
    Create2DPalette ws, Factor, CanvasOffsetDepth, CanvasOffsetWidth, ws.[D3], ws.[E3]
    Create2DPattern ws, Factor, CanvasOffsetDepth, CanvasOffsetWidth, ws.[D2], ws.[E2], ws.[D6], ws.[E6], ws.[J6], ws.[K6], ws.[L6], ws.[M6]
    
    Create2DPalette ws, Factor, CanvasOffsetDepth, CanvasOffsetWidth + 200, ws.[D3], ws.[E3]
    Create2DPattern ws, Factor, CanvasOffsetDepth, CanvasOffsetWidth + 200, ws.[E2], ws.[D2], ws.[D7], ws.[E7], ws.[J7], ws.[K7], ws.[L7], ws.[M7]
End Sub

Public Sub Create2DPalette(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal DrawFactor As Double, ByVal CanvasOffsetDepth As Double, ByVal CanvasOffsetWidth As Double, ByVal PaletteDepth As Double, ByVal PaletteWidth As Double)
    With ws.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, CanvasOffsetWidth, CanvasOffsetDepth, DrawFactor * PaletteWidth, DrawFactor * PaletteDepth)
        .Name = PaletteName
        .BackgroundStyle = msoBackgroundStylePreset2
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub Create2DPattern(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal DrawFactor As Double, ByVal CanvasOffsetDepth As Double, ByVal CanvasOffsetWidth As Double, _
                           ByVal PackageDepth As Double, ByVal PackageWidth As Double, ByVal AmountDepth As Long, ByVal AmountWidth As Long, _
                           ByVal AmountAlternate1Depth As Long, ByVal AmountAlternate1Width As Long, ByVal AmountAlternate2Depth As Long, ByVal AmountAlternate2Width As Long)
    Dim iDepth As Long
    For iDepth = 1 To AmountDepth
        Dim iWidth As Long
        For iWidth = 1 To AmountWidth
            With ws.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, CanvasOffsetWidth + DrawFactor * ((iWidth - 1) * PackageWidth), CanvasOffsetDepth + DrawFactor * ((iDepth - 1) * PackageDepth), DrawFactor * PackageWidth, DrawFactor * PackageDepth)
                .Name = PackageName & iDepth & iWidth
            End With
        Next iWidth
    Next iDepth
    
    
    ' alternate1 (cross width and depth)
    Dim AlternateOffsetDepth As Double
    AlternateOffsetDepth = CanvasOffsetDepth + (AmountDepth * PackageDepth)
    For iDepth = 1 To AmountAlternate1Width
        For iWidth = 1 To AmountAlternate1Depth
            With ws.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, CanvasOffsetWidth + DrawFactor * ((iDepth - 1) * PackageDepth), AlternateOffsetDepth + DrawFactor * ((iWidth - 1) * PackageWidth), DrawFactor * PackageDepth, DrawFactor * PackageWidth)
                .Name = PackageName & iDepth & iWidth
            End With
        Next iWidth
    Next iDepth
    
    ' alternate2 (cross width and depth)
    Dim AlternateOffsetWidth As Double
    AlternateOffsetWidth = CanvasOffsetWidth + (AmountWidth * PackageWidth)
    For iDepth = 1 To AmountAlternate2Depth
        For iWidth = 1 To AmountAlternate2Width
            With ws.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, AlternateOffsetWidth + DrawFactor * ((iDepth - 1) * PackageDepth), CanvasOffsetDepth + DrawFactor * ((iWidth - 1) * PackageWidth), DrawFactor * PackageDepth, DrawFactor * PackageWidth)
                .Name = PackageName & iDepth & iWidth
            End With
        Next iWidth
    Next iDepth
End Sub

Public Sub ClearShapes(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal Name As String)
    Dim Shp As Shape
    For Each Shp In ws.Shapes
        If Left$(Shp.Name, Len(Name)) = Name Then
            Shp.Delete
        End If
    Next Shp
End Sub
```

[image]

These are the formulas I used to calculate the patterns:

```
B6            =D6*E6+(J6*K6)+(L6*M6)
D6            =ROUNDDOWN(D3/D2,0)
E6            =ROUNDDOWN(E3/E2,0)
F6            =D6*D$2
G6            =E6*E$2
H6            =D$3-F6
I6            =E$3-G6
J6            =ROUNDDOWN(H6/E2,0)
K6            =ROUNDDOWN(E3/D2,0)
L6            =ROUNDDOWN(I6/D2,0)
M6            =ROUNDDOWN(D3/E2,0)
B7            =D7*E7+(J7*K7)+(L7*M7)
D7            =ROUNDDOWN(D3/E2,0)
E7            =ROUNDDOWN(E3/D2,0)
F7            =D7*E$2
G7            =E7*D$2
H7            =D$3-F7
I7            =E$3-G7
J7            =ROUNDDOWN(H7/D2,0)
K7            =ROUNDDOWN(E3/E2,0)
L7            =ROUNDDOWN(I7/E2,0)
M7            =ROUNDDOWN(D3/D2,0)
```

Comment: thank you! I will test this out. I think two variations, for now, are fine. however, the 'set ws = Tabelle1' is erroring variable not defined.

Comment: @Sam Of course you need to set it to your worksheet. Either by its VBA name `Set ws = Sheet1` or by its tab name `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`.

Comment: yes, sorry didnt realize it at first, but I got it! thank you so much!

Comment: for one of the variations is it possible to account for overhang? so if something could fit in the pallet but overhang by an inch or two. is there a way to build that in so it is visualized or would there have to be another variation created?

Comment: @Sam You can calculate a possible overhang yourself. You can subtract the `LeftoverWidth` from the `PackageWidth` and you know how much it would hang over. But I highly recommend not to pack pallets overhang (not even one centimeter). If something gets crushed your transport insurance will probably not pay because the pallet was not packed properly. If they find a reason not to pay they don't pay. For visualisation you would need to create more patterns. Also overhangs will get really complicated as there are many ways how to overhang. You would end up with at least 2 or 6 more variations.